# Turn off power to USB port via script

Tags: windows-10, usb, scheduled-tasks

I need to be able to turn off power (not just disable file access) to a specific USB port at a specific time of day, then turn back on at another. This needs to be done without restarting the PC. Does such a command in batch or powershell exist? (Which I could schedule with task scheduler).

Neither of these solutions worked as they did not disable power, or they required a restart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267236/how-disable-and-enable-usb-port-via-command-prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To physically turn USB port power off the port must have power port controller/switch. This feature is optional, and there are not too many systems that decided to put extra expense into an optional feature. See section 11.11 of USB 2.0 Specifications, page 335:

> ... hubs may have power switches that control delivery of power downstream
>   facing ports but it is not required.

Therefore there is no universal means to accomplish your task on an arbitrary-taken system.

To get the desired function ether a host PC  must have the high-side switches (I know some HP systems have the port switches), or you should have a good certified hub with individual port power control (which will be a challenge to get).

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! I really appreciate the work for a solid answer.